# PTRACE_TRACEME error "Operation not permmited"

Tags: c, debugging

I am trying to use PTRACE_TRACEME to trace the child process:

```
if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
   perror("ptrace_traceme");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And I got the error:

```
ptrace_traceme: Operation not permitted
```

As I understood the reason for the issue is security features.

I tried changing from - `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1` to: `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`.

I also checked that SELinux is disabled.
About strace, I saw that strace can solve that problem but I didn't understand how,
something with: `strace -f ./program_name`.

In addition, I run the program as a root and the problem was still not fixed, I start to think that the problem is not related to security features.

BTW, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.